# Manually mark unchanged document content as changed

Tags: microsoft-word, change-tracking

I made some changes to a document before remembering to enable change tracking. Is there a way I can select some text and forcibly tell MSWord "mark this as changed"?

Comment: Not really. You can add comments to it. Or you can delete it, enable change tracking and paste it back, so it'll be marked as new.

Comment: Or if there are many changes you can compare original version (if you have it) with new version using Compare button on a Review tab (in Word 2010) - and selecting that you want to show changes in revised document. Remember to make a backup first.

Answer (score 4):

As there is no command to do that, here is what I usually do to mark some text as “changed”, without removing the tracking:

- Select all the text you want to mark,
- Cut it,
- Accept the removal,
- Paste it back.

⋅
⋅
⋅

Here is a GIF (with some french language inside the contextual menu, but it's easy to understand!) :

[image: Mark as modified]

I hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

I wasnt happy with this answer - but stumbled by accident on another way.

Simply mark the block you want to put a revision mark next to - then go to the FONTS and change the font color and change it back.

Works a treat in Word 2016